# How to compare all documents in two collections with millions of doc and write the diff in a third collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have two collections (coll_1, coll_2) with a million documents each.

These two collections are actually created by running two versions of a code from the same data source, so both two collections will have the same number of documents but the document in both collections can have one more field or sub-document missing or have a different values, but both collection's documents will have **the same primary_key_id** which is indexed.

I have this javascript function saved on the db to get the diff

```
db.system.js.save({
    _id: "diffJSON", value:
    function(obj1, obj2) {
        var result = {};
        for (key in obj1) {
            if (obj2[key] != obj1[key]) result[key] = obj2[key];
            if (typeof obj2[key] == 'array' && typeof obj1[key] == 'array')
                result[key] = arguments.callee(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
            if (typeof obj2[key] == 'object' && typeof obj1[key] == 'object')
                result[key] = arguments.callee(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
        }
        return result;
    }
});
```

Which runs fine like this

```
diffJSON(testObj1, testObj2);
```

**Question:** How to run diffJSON on coll1 and coll2, and output diffJSON result into coll3 along with primary_key_id.

I am new to MongoDB, and I understand the JOINS doesn't work as similar to RDBMS, so I wonder if I have to copy the two comparing documents in a single collection and then run the diffJSON function.

Also, most of the time (say 90%) documents in two collections will be identical, I would need to know about only 10% of docs which have any diff.

Here is a simple example document:
(but real doc is around 15k in size, just so you know the scale)

```
var testObj1 = { test:"1",test1: "2", tt:["td","ax"], tr:["Positive"] ,tft:{test:["a"]}};
var testObj2 = { test:"1",test1: "2", tt:["td","ax"], tr:["Negative"] };
```

If you know a better way to diff the documents, please feel free to suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a simple shell script to achieve this. First create a file named `script.js` and paste this code in it :

```
// load previously saved diffJSON() function
db.loadServerScripts();

// get all the document from collection coll1
var cursor = db.coll1.find(); 

if (cursor != null && cursor.hasNext()) {
  // iterate over the cursor 
  while (cursor.hasNext()){
   var doc1 = cursor.next();
   // get the doc with the same _id from coll2 
   var id = doc1._id; 
   var doc2 = db.coll2.findOne({_id: id});
   // compute the diff 
   var diff = diffJSON(doc2, doc1);
   // if there is a difference between the two objects
   if ( Object.keys(diff).length > 0 ) {
     diff._id = id;
     // insert the diff in coll3 with the same _id
     db.coll3.insert(diff);
   }
  }
}
```

In this script I assume that your **primary_key** is the `_id` field.

then execute it from you shell like this:

```
mongo --host hostName --port portNumber databaseName < script.js
```

where `databaseName` is the came of the database containing the collections `coll1` and `coll2`.

for this samples documents (just added an `_id` field to your docs):

```
var testObj1 = { _id: 1, test:"1",test1: "2", tt:["td","ax"], tr:["Positive"] ,tft:{test:["a"]}};
var testObj2 = { _id: 1, test:"1",test1: "2", tt:["td","ax"], tr:["Negative"] };
```

the script will save the following doc in `coll3` :

```
 { "_id" : 1, "tt" : {  }, "tr" : { "0" : "Positive" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution builds upon the one proposed by felix (I don't have the necessary reputation to comment on his). I made a few small changes to his script that bring important performance improvements:

```js
// load previously saved diffJSON() function
db.loadServerScripts();

// get all the document from collection coll1 and coll2
var cursor1 = db.coll1.find().sort({'_id': 1});
var cursor2 = db.coll2.find().sort({'_id': 1});

if (cursor1 != null && cursor1.hasNext() && cursor2 != null && cursor2.hasNext()) {
  // iterate over the cursor
  while (cursor1.hasNext() && cursor2.hasNext()){
   var doc1 = cursor1.next();
   var doc2 = cursor2.next();
   var pk = doc1._id
   // compute the diff
   var diff = diffJSON(doc2, doc1);
   // if there is a difference between the two objects

   if ( Object.keys(diff).length > 0 ) {
     diff._id = pk;
     // insert the diff in coll3 with the same _id
     db.coll3.insert(diff);
   }
  }
}
```

Two cursors are used for fetching all the entries in the database **sorted by the primary key**. This is a very important aspect and brings most of the performance improvement. By retrieving the documents sorted by primary key, we make sure we match them correctly by the primary key. This is based on the fact that the two collections hold the same data.

This way we avoid making a call to coll2 for each document in coll1. It might seem as something insignificant, but we're talking about 1 million calls which put a lot of stress on the database.

Another important assumption is that the primary key field is **_id**. If it's not the case, it is crucial to have an **unique** index on the primary key field. Otherwise, the script might mismatch documents with the same primary key.